# What DLL is sw_find_class in?

Tags: windows, qt, dll, smoke

When something is undefined, such as sw_find_class, which is probably supposed to be in a DLL, how do you find out what DLL it's supposed to be in?

I think sw_find_class might have something to do with Smoke or QT.

Is there a program to search all the DLL's on your computer to find something like that?

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is off-topic on SO. It is better suited for [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's not a library recommendation.  It's an undefined symbol, which might or might not be in a particular DLL.

Comment: The *canonical, correct* solution is to look at the documentation for the function in question.  And if you don't have the documentation you shouldn't be calling the function.  But FWIW the functions a DLL exports are part of the DLL and stored as plain ASCII text, so you can use any search tool that looks at the content of a file, e.g., `findstr`.